# Awk- Commands for txt output (size, bold options)

Tags: linux, awk, txt

I was wondering if there was any possibility to specify a desired text SIZE or **bold** option as in Microsoft Word, when printing the output of specific strings in AWK.

I'm generating a report and it needs to be kind of visual and clear for the reader.

The input is an AWK script.

Do you know of any commands that could come in handy?

Many thanks!

Comment: Joseph, `awk` operates on plain text, and is typically used in a terminal environment. While many terminals can interpret ESC sequences to mean bold, underline or even certain colours, this is not something awk is intended to do.

Comment: Hi @tink, thanks for your answer. But if the output is redirected to a txt file, could we do something about it?

Comment: if you know the hex (or octal) control codes for the desired attribute (eg, SIZE, color, bold, italics, etc) you could have `awk` include said control codes in its output; whether the terminal is able to interpret the control codes would depend on the codes and the terminal type; same goes for `awk` writing its output to a file ... display of the attributes will be based on an application's ability to interpret the control codes when loading/reading the file; run a web search on `awk print color codes` to get some ideas on how `awk` can print control codes

Comment: It's not clear what you're really trying to do but you might be better off generating HTML from awk  and then viewing the result in a browser or similar and printing from there as PDF or whatever you like.

Comment: As Ed says, if you want formatting, then the output format will need to be something other than plain text. You're producing a report of some kind?  HTML is definitely doable, but markdown may be easier from a script.